# Free-space dyadic Green function

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, greens-functions

My professor derived the free-space dyadic Green function from the general Green function:
$$\tag{1}
\stackrel{\leftrightarrow}{\boldsymbol{G}}=\left[\stackrel{\leftrightarrow}{\mathbb{I}}+\frac{1}{k^{2}} \nabla \nabla\right] G_{0}(R)$$
With the scalar Green function:
$$\tag{2}
G_{0}(R)=\frac{e^{i k R}}{4 \pi R}, \quad R \equiv\left|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}^{\prime}\right|$$
In the derivation, he states the following:
$$\tag{3}
\nabla \hat{\mathbf{R}}=\nabla\left(\frac{\mathbf{R}}{R}\right)=\frac{\nabla \mathbf{R}}{R}+\mathbf{R} \nabla \frac{1}{R}$$
where $\boldsymbol{R}=\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}^{\prime}, \quad \widehat{\boldsymbol{R}}=\frac{\boldsymbol{R}}{R}$. He says we can see from eq. (3) that $\nabla \mathbf{R}=\mathbb{I}$, but I don't see that? Can someone explain how he gets to that conclusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\nabla \mathbf{R}$ this is vector direct product (or tensor product).  A definition in wiki:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product.

$$
\vec{\nabla} \vec{R} = \left( \hat{e_1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} +  \hat{e_2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} +  \hat{e_3} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_3} \right)  \left( \hat{e_1} R_1 +  \hat{e_2} R_2 +  \hat{e_3} R_3 \right) \\
= \hat{e_1}\hat{e_1}  \frac{\partial R_1}{\partial x_1} +\hat{e_1}\hat{e_2}  \frac{\partial R_2}{\partial x_1} +\hat{e_1}\hat{e_3}  \frac{\partial R_3}{\partial x_1} \\
+\hat{e_2}\hat{e_1}  \frac{\partial R_1}{\partial x_2} +\hat{e_2}\hat{e_2}  \frac{\partial R_2}{\partial x_2} +\hat{e_2}\hat{e_3}  \frac{\partial R_3}{\partial x_2} \\
+ \hat{e_3}\hat{e_1}  \frac{\partial R_1}{\partial x_3} +\hat{e_3}\hat{e_2}  \frac{\partial R_2}{\partial x_3} +\hat{e_3}\hat{e_3}  \frac{\partial R_3}{\partial x_3}  
$$

Since $\vec{R} = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$, this leads to:

$$
\vec{\nabla} \vec{R} = \hat{e_1}\hat{e_1}  \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_1} +\hat{e_1}\hat{e_2}  \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial x_1} +\hat{e_1}\hat{e_3}  \frac{\partial x_3}{\partial x_1} \\
+\hat{e_2}\hat{e_1}  \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_2} +\hat{e_2}\hat{e_2}  \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial x_2} +\hat{e_2}\hat{e_3}  \frac{\partial x_3}{\partial x_2} \\
+ \hat{e_3}\hat{e_1}  \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_3} +\hat{e_3}\hat{e_2}  \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial x_3} +\hat{e_3}\hat{e_3}  \frac{\partial x_3}{\partial x_3} \\
=\bf{I} 
$$

Edition in response to the comment of superciocia for dyadic to act on a vector function: $\vec f = \hat x f_x + \hat y f_y + \hat z f_z$.
\begin{align}
\vec{\nabla} \vec{R} \vec f &= 
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\0&0&1
  \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} f_x\\ f_y\\f_z
  \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} f_x\\ f_y\\f_z
  \end{bmatrix} = \hat x f_x + \hat y f_y + \hat z f_z = \vec f\\
\end{align}

Comment: I am not so familiar with dyadic expressions ... my question would be, isn't it true that, for the standard basis in $\mathbb{R}^3$:

Comment: $\vec{\nabla} \vec{R} = \hat{e_1}\hat{e_1}  \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_1} +\hat{e_1}\hat{e_2}  \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial x_1} +\hat{e_1}\hat{e_3}  \frac{\partial x_3}{\partial x_1} \\
+\hat{e_2}\hat{e_1}  \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_2} +\hat{e_2}\hat{e_2}  \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial x_2} +\hat{e_2}\hat{e_3}  \frac{\partial x_3}{\partial x_2} \\
+ \hat{e_3}\hat{e_1}  \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_3} +\hat{e_3}\hat{e_2}  \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial x_3} +\hat{e_3}\hat{e_3}  \frac{\partial x_3}{\partial x_3} \\
=3 ?$

Comment: This solution seems however to cause a contradiction
$
(\vec{\nabla} \vec{R})\vec{f} = 3\vec{f} \neq \vec{f} = \bf{I} \vec{f} $

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: @SuperCiocia I appended some lines to explain you worry. The dyadic is a matrix, not a scale.